# Inserting polygon as GeoJSON in PostGIS with only boundry coordinates

Tags: postgis, polygon, postgresql, geojson, insert

I am trying to insert GeoJSON polygon features into a PostGIS DB. The input coordinate points are only the left-top corner and the bottom right corner. I have tried to use the `ST_MakeEnvelope`, but it is not working.

```
CREATE TABLE geojsonpoly (
    id serial PRIMARY KEY,
    name VARCHAR(64),
    polygon GEOMETRY
);


insert into geojsonpoly(name,polygon)
values('poly1',ST_SetSRID(
ST_GeomFromGeoJSON('
{"type":"Polygon",
"coordinates":[
[
ST_MakeEnvelope(
-114.017347,51.048005,
-114.005899,51.045381
)
]
]}
'),4326));
```

The only part I am struggling with the the "coordinates": where I need to use any method that can return a rectangular polygon from two points.

Answer (score 6):

PostGIS has no concept of *GeoJSON* - except for the I/O functionality, which translates between the internal and the *GeoJSON* representation of geometric features. Likewise does your exemplary input not look like a *GeoJSON* representation.

If the cell maxima are in fact simple pairs of *coordinates*, you'd simply need to **rearrange** them to fit the `xmin,ymin,xmax,ymax` order (i.e. derived from the bottom-left & top-right corners) of `ST_MakeEnvelope`:

```
CREATE TABLE geojsonpoly (
    id     INT GENERATED BY DEFAULT AS IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY,
    "name" VARCHAR(64),
    geom   GEOMETRY(POLYGON, 4326)
);

INSERT INTO
  geojsonpoly ("name", geom)
VALUES
  ( 'poly1', ST_MakeEnvelope(<xmin>, <ymin>, <xmax>, <ymax>, 4326) )
;
```

Comment: many thanks i was a bit confused as the concept is new for me. that worked perfectly for me.

Comment: @user9995 glad it helped. Consider *accepting* this answer then to let other users know it solved your problem.